# Questions about phantom 4 pro, connection and programming method of inspire 2

Tags: dji-sdk

이후선

11月7日 CST14:30

1. Can Phantom 4 and Inspire 2 be programmed on a PC?

   - I wonder if I can program the drones directly through the PC and acquire the images.
2. Phantom 4 has a smart device attached. I wonder if I can use the other smart device (iPhone, iPad) to control the dron without using the smart device which is basically installed.
3. In case of Inspire 2, I use smart device and controller with USB connection. I wonder if smart device and controller can be connected wirelessly without using USB.
4. I am curious about the communication method of Phantom 4 and Inspire 2.

   - I wonder what communication frequency should be used to directly control the drone via PC.
5. I wonder if I can program Phantom 4, Inspire 2 using the DJI Developer-ONBOARD SDK.

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you would need to use the mobile SDK as a bridge (PC talks to the mobile app, mobile app controls the aircraft)
2. I'm not sure which smart device you mention. If you mention the Phantom 4 Pro remote controller with attached screen, you can just swap to a regular remote without and use an iOS or Android device. In case of the Crystal Sky, you can simply remove it and use another device.
3. Unfortunately no.
4. PC control see #1, frequency, 2.4 and 5.8 GHz are commonly used and configurable using DJI Go.
5. Unfortunately no, for OnBoardSDK supported products see at the bottom of [this page.](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet. So this is rather additional option how to get video/images from Phantom 4 to PC directly.

1.In the menu of DJI GO app you can setup video streaming, trough RTMP. So video in resolution 720p will be stream.See this tutorial https://afsyaw.wordpress.com/2017/07/06/processing-images-from-the-dji-matrice-100-and-zenmuse-x3-without-the-manifold/

2.While on your Linux machine you can setup video stream server such as NGINX.Tutorial here https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/

3.Than you can use OpenCV usb-video lib for ROS to process video or images.

If you have Matrice 100. There is also existing HDMI port on the controller. If you will use USB-HDMI grabber such as Immilet or Magwel - both support Mac,Windows,Linux drivers.You can skip step 1, also video stream is better.